# Linear map and inner products

Tags: orthonormal

How can one check that a map $L: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ preserves an inner product, provided that the basis with respect to the inner product is orthonormal?

Comment: One checks that $\langle u,v\rangle = \langle Lu,Lv\rangle$. If the basis $B$ is orthonormal, one checks that $L(B)$ is also an orthonormal basis.

Comment: If $L: \mathbb{V} \to \mathbb{V}$ is any map and we have two inner products defined on $\mathbb{V}$, $[ , ]$ and $⟨ , ⟩$, and we pick two orthonormal bases w.r.t. each of these inner products, how do we prove that if $L(B) = A$ (where $A$ and $B$ are the two bases), then L preserves the inner product, and thus $[x, y] = ⟨L(x), L(y)⟩$?